# Keycloak: how to verify token gotten from service A in service B?

Tags: oauth, jwt, keycloak

I have a service `A` and `B`. I am running up keycloak service in the same container with service `A`.

So, configs for service `A` are the following:

```ini
[app]
PageSize = 10
JwtSecret = 233
PrefixUrl = http://127.0.0.1:8000

[sso]
Host = http://127.0.0.1:8080
AdminLogin = some_admin
AdminPassword = some_password
Realm = master
ClientID = my_client
ClientSecret = XXX
```

I set up a middleware that validates JWT (gotten by keycloak) in service `A` and it successfully works out.

I run service `B` in another container with this config:

```ini
[app]
PageSize = 10
JwtSecret = 233
PrefixUrl = http://127.0.0.1:8002

[sso]
Host = http://172.18.0.1:8080
AdminLogin = some_admin
AdminPassword = some_password
Realm = master
ClientID = my_client
ClientSecret = XXX
```

You have noticed that I couldn't use `127.0.0.1` in `B`'s config because it cannot dial this address (because keycloak is running with `A` in the same container).

I use the same JWT in the request header for service `B`. After that it goes to keycloak and gets:

```json
{
    "code": "ERROR_AUTH_CHECK_TOKEN_FAIL",
    "context": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "401 Unauthorized: invalid_token: Token verification failed",
        "type": "unknown"
    }
}
```

Am I right that keycloak detects the proxing somehow and the error is thrown because of that?

Should I use separate clients for keycloak for both services? And if it is so, how do I verify JWT gotten from service `A` in the `B` service?

Comment: to verify the token apart from jwt verification, keycloak check several things like session, client etc. It's weird that you wanna verify the token in the irrelevant keycloak.

Comment: @MuhammedYalçınKuru what is a right way to verify user that goes to `B`?

Comment: even if when you are in the B, you should verify your token in the service A.  that means you should separate the keycloak container.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. Ticket that I got from `A` had the issuer host `http://127.0.0.1:8080` and `B` sent a header with the host `http://172.18.0.1:8080` that failed token validation. Briefly, these hosts must be the same